# Scope of menu shortcut key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem, keyboard-shortcuts

When I click menu strip and then press shortcut key it works but it does not work otherwise. Is there something to set scope of shortcut key?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="NewGUI_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=RecentFileListLib"
    Title="Sezor" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Icon="/NewGUI_WPF;component/Images/i161.ICO" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" Focusable="False" ResizeMode="CanResize" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="243" d:DesignWidth="314" SizeToContent="Manual" WindowState="Maximized">

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="SaveCommand" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="OpenCommand" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Grid>
    <Menu Height="23" Name="main_menu" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsMainMenu="True">
        <MenuItem Name="MI_Case" Header="Case">
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="Open">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="/NewGUI_WPF;component/Images/openHS.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Name="MainMenu_File_Save" Command="Save">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="/NewGUI_WPF;component/Images/saveHS.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Save as" Name="MainMenu_File_SaveAs" Click="MainMenu_File_SaveAs_Click" />
            <common:RecentFileList x:Name="RecentFileList" />
            <MenuItem Header="Quit" Click="MainMenu_File_Quit_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="View">
            <MenuItem Header="Input File" Click="MainMenu_View_InputFile_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Mesh File" Click="MainMenu_View_meshFile_Click" />
            <MenuItem Name="MainMenu_View_Summary" Header="Summary" Click="MainMenu_View_summary_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Define" >
            <MenuItem Header="Input File" Click="MainMenu_Define_InputFile_Click" Name="MainMenu_Define_InputFile" />
            <MenuItem Header="Mesh File" Click="MainMenu_Define_MeshFile_Click" Name="MainMenu_Define_MeshFile" />
            <MenuItem Header="Simulation File" Click="MainMenu_Define_SimulFile_Click" Name="MainMenu_Define_SimulFile" />
            <MenuItem Header="Boundaries" Click="MainMenu_Define_BC_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Initials" Click="MainMenu_Define_Initials_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Spatial Discretization" Click="MainMenu_Define_SpatDis_Click" />                
            <MenuItem Header="Flow" Click="MainMenu_Define_Flow_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Material" Click="MainMenu_Define_Material" />
            <MenuItem Header="Algoritm" Click="MainMenu_Define_Algoritm" />
            <MenuItem Header="Gradient Reconstruction">
                <RadioButton Content="Least-Squares" Checked="Least_Squares_Checked" Name="rad_GR_LS" />
                <RadioButton Content="Green-Gauss" Click="Green_Gauss_Checked" Name="rad_GR_GG" />
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Run" >
            <MenuItem Header="Simulation" Click="MainMenu_Run_Simulation_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Frame Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,60,30,20" Name="frm_summary" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
    <StatusBar Height="23" Name="statusBar1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0">
        <TextBlock Name="statBar_text_1"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

**Code:**

```
private void OpenCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {...}  
private void SaveCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {...}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I entered your code above verbatim into a new WPF project and it actually works fine for me. I'm running Windows 7 and compiling with Visual Studio 2010. What are you using?

Comment: Also, can you try the example I pasted below to see if that also doesn't work on your system? You might wanna test this out on a different development box in case there's a weird input quirk on the one you're using.

Comment: Also, since `control-s` is the default for the `Save` command, it seems you can leave out the `Window.InputBindings` section. I did so on my system and the key binding worked.

Comment: Mine is also win7 and VS10. The thing is, my menu is in a grid, yours is not. I tried yours and it works. May it be because of grid?

Comment: Can you post the complete XAML and code-behind of a minimal example which demonstrates the problem? I.e. the menu inside the grid? :-) I wrapped the minimal example below in a grid and the key bindings still function on my system.

Comment: Yeah, it is not because of grid (I tried in yours). Anyway I added complete XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Focusable="False"` in your `Window` tag.

Comment: @shibli No problem! Glad we found the problem. Posting the exact code always helps. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add `CanExecute` to the `CommandBinding` and a corresponding code behind method.

Here's a minimal demonstration that wires up `Control-S` to launch the `Help` command.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflow___scope_of_menu_shortcut_key.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Help" CanExecute="HelpCanExecute" Executed="HelpExecuted"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="Help" Key="S" Modifiers="Control"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Help" Name="HelpMenu" Command="Help"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace stackoverflow___scope_of_menu_shortcut_key
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HelpCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void HelpExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that if you comment out the line:

```
e.CanExecute = true;
```

the key bindings no longer function.

Here's your example, stripped down to a bare minimum. This works on my system:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflow___scope_of_menu_shortcut_key.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="MyCommand" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"/>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace stackoverflow___scope_of_menu_shortcut_key
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but situation is still same.